# Obtain the indexes of one vector into another vector but keeping the order

Tags: r

Let us say I have two vectors a, and b,

```
a = c(1,21,3,42,5,6,7,8,9)
b = c(2,5,7,10,3,40,1,21,42,6,8,9)
```

If I do:

```
which(b %in% a)
```

I obtain,

```
 2  3  5  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

But I'd like to keep the order in which they appear, i.e., I'd like to have as the output,

```
7 8 5 9 2 10 3 11 12
```

since 1 is in position 7 in b, 21 is in position 8 in b, etc.

Is that easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `match` instead, but note that `match` and `%in%` don't do exactly the same thing:

```
> match(a, b)
[1]  7  8  5  9  2 10  3 11 12
```

Comment: +1! `match(a, b, nomatch = 0)` to get the same thing as `%in%`